# Parse output of a command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, supervisord

I am running supervisord service on my server to run two binaries. From a shell script I am updating the RPMs for the two. When I update them, I want to check if they are running or not. If yes, then it gives a stop command to stop the binaries. If not, then the error message should not be printed. Here is my sample output and script:

```
root>test-rc-002@/home/lab>supervisorctl status all
Binary1                            RUNNING   pid 5444, uptime 0:04:12
Binary2                            RUNNING   pid 5445, uptime 0:04:12

root>test-rc-002@/home/lab>service supervisord stop
Stopping supervisord (via systemctl):                      [  OK  ]

root>test-rc-002@/home/lab>supervisorctl status all
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
```

Here is part of script:

```
supervisorctl stop Binary1
supervisorctl stop Binary2
service supervisord stop

PID=`ps -eaf | grep /opt/abcd/binary1/binary1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "" !=  "$PID" ]]; then
  echo "killing $PID"
  kill -9 $PID
fi
```

What I want to do is:

1) Check the status through -  supervisorctl status all

```
Binary1                            RUNNING   pid 5444, uptime 0:04:12
Binary2                            RUNNING   pid 5445, uptime 0:04:12
```

2) If they are running, then only pass commands -

```
supervisorctl stop Binary1
supervisorctl stop Binary2
service supervisord stop
```

3) If they are not running, then "refused connection" will come somewhere in the message, take it and then move to the PID killing part. The message should not be printed on terminal.

I am new to shell scripting and not able to parse the output. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing the lines in the file you can pass each line to another function which will receive the lines as $1 $2 etc. For example:

```sh
sub()
{     if [ $2 = "RUNNING" ]; then
        echo RUNNING
      else
          echo "not running"
     fi
}

sub asdf RUNNING asfasf
sub asdfa asdfasdf asfdasd
```